# How can emulator show no status bar space and physical device shows it in Compose View?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-jetpack-compose, fullscreen

We are trying to show the app in full screen whilst reproducing a portrait video. Emulator hides correctly the system bars but physical device is leaving a black space in lieu of the status bar.

[image: Emulator]
vs
[image: Physical Device]

We are currently setting the app in full screen with:
`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` at the onCreate and hiding system bars with:

```
 val windowInsetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
        windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
```

When entering full screen on the video player.